# GPG: conventions for adding a UID that isn't an email

Tags: gnupg

I want to add various accounts to my GPG public key, e.g. GitHub and Twitter, so that others can verify that they are my accounts. Is there any convention for this?

Usually the UID is defined in the format: `Name (comment) <email>`

My first ideas would be: `Username (service)` or `Name (service) <username>`

Comment: https://help.github.com/categories/gpg/

Comment: I know about adding a GPG public key *to* GitHub and Twitter but neither of those methods help me to prove prove that I own those accounts.

Comment: [How to prove the ownership of a public git/github repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17467155)

Comment: https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2014/03/19/Keybase: "Keybase.io does a few simple things: ... Lets you prove that the owner of a key also owns a particular Twitter handle and Github account. "

Comment: After looking at the GitHub link again, I can see where you're coming from and that seems sensible. What about for Twitter instead?

Answer (score 0):

The historical answer to this was something like https://keybase.io/. However, I'd argue that the answer in 2023 (after KeyBase was acquired by Zoom and, so far as I know, left to languish) is to make those claims as *signature notations within the keypair*, along with using [keyoxide](https://docs.keyoxide.org/understanding-keyoxide/keyoxide/), a decentralized system for establishing bi-directional proofs between OpenPGP keypairs and various online identities, to verify those claims.

The basic idea is that you have claims of the form `proof@ariadne.id=https://gist.github.com/aspensmonster/7c1feac1cf55445b54acacf03493a642` as a signature notation on the keypair, and Keyoxide clients can then validate whether or not that particular gist contains evidence of pointing back to the keypair. This relies upon the transport layer between the Keyoxide client and its target being secure (TLS typically), and the proof URL being editable solely by the intended claim-user (hence username-scoped gists, in GitHub's case). As an example, my keypair fingerprint is `79895B2E0F87503F1DDE80B649765D7F0DDD9BD5`, and it has the aforementioned signature notation associated with the keypair. Visiting that GitHub gist URL shows the following content:

> This is an OpenPGP proof that connects my OpenPGP key to this GitHub account. For details check out https://docs.keyoxide.org/advanced/openpgp-proofs/
>
> [Verifying my OpenPGP key: openpgp4fpr:79895B2E0F87503F1DDE80B649765D7F0DDD9BD5]

The Keyoxide client observes that the fingerprints match, and reports back that the signature notation claim on the keypair has been verified/validated/proven on the other end.